# How can I set a Page Title with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The site that I'm working on has really crappy title structure and can't be changed for a variety of reasons. Can I "set" the page title for Google Analytics via JS somehow?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The New Way

There's a (currently undocumented feature) that allows you to override the current page's title:

```
_gaq.push(["_set", "title", "Your Brand New Page Title"]);
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]); //will send with the overridden page title
```

---

### The Old Way

Google Analytics gets the title information from `document.title`, so you could just set document.title before Google Analytics runs to whatever value you want it to be.

```
_gaq.push(function(){
    var oldtitle = document.title; 
    document.title = "More Descriptive Title";
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
    document.title = oldtitle;
});
```

Tests in Chrome seem to indicate that this doesn't cause a title flicker, but your results may vary.

Comment: You can use `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])` inside the function. Once ga.js is loaded push will run right away before you set back the page title. So you don't need the _getTrackerByName part.

Comment: @eduardocereto hm, good point. It just feels weird to do a `_gaq.push()` within a `_gaq.push()`. :P

Comment: I agree, at first I thought that the inside _gaq.push would be delaed to be executed after the function finished. But after some tests I realised it doesn't. I asked some Googlers abojut it and they said that's the desired effect and probably won't change.

Comment: For anyone arriving here to set the page name too, this can be achieved with `_gaq.push(['_set', 'page', 'PAGE NAME HERE']);`, And of course, this is undocumented.

Answer (score 13):

This is different in analytics.js (Universal Analytics).

Find details on [Google's developer site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages).

**Here are Snippets from the Site:**

To send a pageview, you pass the ga function a send command with the pageview hit type:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

When this command is executed, the analytics.js library sets the title value using the document.title browser property.

**Overriding Default Values**

If you need to override the default location information, you should update the title and page values directly.

To override the default page value, you can pass the ga command an additional parameter:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/my-overridden-page?id=1');
```

Alternatively, to override these values, the send command accepts an optional field object as the last parameter. The field object is a standard JavaScript object, but defines specific field names and values accepted by analytics.js.

```
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my-overridden-page?id=1',
  'title': 'my overridden page'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely accomplish this in Google Analytics. GA pulls the title information from document.title, so you could just set document.title before GA runs to whatever value you want it to be. In your GA code to push you would set the following:

```
_gaq.push(["_set", "title", "Your Brand New Page Title"]);
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]); //will send with the overridden page title
```

Comment: Linked post don`t have any additional information about Google Analytics.